# Ubuntu raring apt-get update is failing on AWS/EC2?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-13.04

I'm working with a StarCluster AMI, and trying to install my software onto it. However, I'm having trouble with `apt-get`. I try to install a package:

```
(! 141)-> sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  postgresql-client-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 132 kB of archives.
After this operation, 634 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? y
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main postgresql-client-common all 140
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring/main postgresql-common all 140
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-client-common_140_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postgresql-common/postgresql-common_140_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

but that fails. I'm out of sync somehow with the repositories:

```
(! 127)-> sudo apt-get update
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5 Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg           
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5 Release               
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                                      
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                       
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5/contrib Sources                             
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources/DiffIndex                      
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release           
Hit http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release.gpg                                            
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources/DiffIndex                  
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                      
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                  
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources/DiffIndex              
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring Release                                                
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                                           
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex       
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages                                    
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5/contrib Translation-en_US                   
Ign http://archive.cloudera.com squeeze-cdh3u5/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources                     
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main amd64 Packages              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en   
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US           
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en              
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US           
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources          
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en              
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en_US           
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages   
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net raring/main Translation-en              
Err http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
Err http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-security/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring-updates/universe/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

But those servers are reachable:

```
(! 129)-> ping 91.189.92.200
PING 91.189.92.200 (91.189.92.200) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.200: icmp_req=1 ttl=46 time=153 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.200: icmp_req=2 ttl=46 time=153 ms
64 bytes from 91.189.92.200: icmp_req=3 ttl=46 time=148 ms
^C
--- 91.189.92.200 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 148.362/151.713/153.471/2.413 ms
```

and my DNS is working:

```
(! 156)-> host us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com
us-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com is an alias for archive.ubuntu.com.
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.24
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.92.200
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.92.201
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.88.149
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.13
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.15
archive.ubuntu.com has address 91.189.91.23
archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8c01::18
archive.ubuntu.com has IPv6 address 2001:67c:1360:8c01::19
```

For reference:

```
(! 145)-> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.04
Release:    13.04
Codename:   raring
```

In case it matters, the image was initiated with:

```
starcluster start -o -s 1 -I m3.medium -m ami-80bedfb0 imagehost
```

(well, to be exact, I started it in my AWS console with a larger volume, saved that as an image, and then ran starcluster with my ami.)

My instance is in `us-west-2a`, and the security group appears to allow the required connections. Is this because raring is no longer supported? Has anybody encountered this and/or is there a solution other than installing my packages in `/usr/local`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 13.04 is no longer supported, the repo mirrors have dropped the packages - thus the 404 errors you're seeing.

Switch to the `old-releases.ubuntu.com` mirror and upgrade to a supported version, as is detailed in the documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why the URL has to be different for supported vs non supported distros since the distro's name doesn't change when it stops being supported. Maybe it's a business model decision?

Comment: @amos I'd guess it's to force people to realize that they're no longer getting updates - running `apt-get update` then `apt-get upgrade` on an ancient version of the OS and getting no errors at all would give a false impression that you're up to date, when you're really running software that's not getting any patches.